# Is it possible to crop multiple image using cloudinary?

Tags: cloudinary

Is it possible to upload and crop multiple images using Cloudinary (Javascript/React-JS) ?

Any help shall be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Upload API, you can upload multiple files in succession and send the cropping coordinates for each in the `custom_coordinates` property: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_optional_parameters

I assume from your question that you're not uploading directly though, and are using the Upload Widget on your page.

If so, the cropping interface only works when uploading a single file, so to upload multiple files and let the user choose crop coordinates for each, you'll need to open the widget multiple times in succession: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget_reference#cropping_parameters